# Simple javascript counter that can be paused and resumed after web page has been closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to create a very simple Javascript-based counter, which counts currency (so two decimal places) and increases in value by 0.18 every minute. The idea is to represent "live" estimated savings by the company's new solar panels, and this counter will be started and stopped by an employee every day, to continue the next day.

I found a fiddle by somebody else for a start/resume counter: http://jsfiddle.net/f9X6J/
HTML:

```
<span id="hour"></span>
<span id="min"></span>
<span id="sec"></span>
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
<input id="resumeButton" type="button" value="Resume">
```

Javascript:

```
  var Clock = {
  totalSeconds: 1000,

  start: function () {
    var self = this;

    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
      self.totalSeconds += 1;

      $("#hour").text(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600));
      $("#min").text(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
      $("#sec").text(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60));
    }, 1000);
  },

  pause: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
  },

  resume: function () {
    if (!this.interval) this.start();
  }
};

Clock.start();

$('#pauseButton').click(function () { Clock.pause(); });
$('#resumeButton').click(function () { Clock.resume(); });
```

This is great so far, but I please need the following:

1. It must not calculate time, but rather money.
2. It must be saved to the server in case the computer shuts off.

Thanks!

Comment: count the minuets not the seconds, then just times this number by 0.18.  if the timer only runs once a minuet then it shouldn't be a burden to update the server every minuet.

Comment: This isn't a code request section but a code help section i.e. you post a problem, what you need, what you tried not what you have and what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I apologize if I asked incorrectly. I'm a beginner when it comes to Javascript, so my attempt at getting it to work was to find the abovementioned jsfiddle. I don't necessarily need code, just a point in the right direction.

Thanks krisph, that's quite a smart idea!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of beginners in 2019. The answer to the two questions are,

1) Keep a counter outside the clock object and keep adding 1 to it every second the clock is active. This will give the total number of seconds the clock has been active. This can be then converted to total savings at any point.

2) Don't jump on to server side stuff just yet. Try to store the total with localStorage which persists even if the computer is switched off until browsing data is cleared in the browser. This will avoid lot of added complexity. An example for storing values locally and reading from them is below.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="counter"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var counter;
    if( localStorage.getItem("counter") == null) { 
      counter = 0;
      localStorage.setItem("counter", counter); 
    } else {
      counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    }
    document.getElementById('counter').textContent = counter;
    setInterval(function(){
      counter = parseInt(counter)+1;
      localStorage.setItem("counter", counter); 
      document.getElementById('counter').textContent = counter;
    },1000);
  </script>
</html>
```

Hope this provides a right direction.